# Nesting async.parallel calls?

Tags: node.js

So I have the following code structure in Node:

```
async.parallel({
   firstTask: function firstTask(callback) {
      var firstCall = makeNetworkCall();
      callback(null, firstCall);
   },
   secondTask: function secondTask(callback) {
      var secondTaskInputArguments = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      // want to make five parallel network calls to the same endpoint,
      // with each one of these five network requests
      // taking an item from the above list as input
   } 
},
function handler(err, results) {
    var firstCallResults = results.firstCall;
    // want to also grab five results from five parallel network calls in secondTask
});
```

In my `secondTask`, I want to make five parallel requests to a second endpoint. What's the best way to do this? I could nest `async.parallel` calls (i.e. put an `async.parallel` call in the second task), but this gets messy. I could also just put the five parallel calls in the outer `async.parallel`, but also messy. What's the preferred way to accomplish something like this? (perhaps with different syntax?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `async.forEach`. Since you have an array of arguments, this is the perfect case for it! async.forEach calls the provided function on each element in the array and calls back once every callback of those functions has been called. Be warned that any errors passed to the callback of async.forEach will cause it to execute its callback code.

```
async.parallel({
   firstTask: function firstTask(callback) {
      var firstCall = makeNetworkCall();
      callback(null, firstCall);
   },
   secondTask: function secondTask(callback) {
      var secondTaskInputArguments = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      async.forEach(secondTaskInputArguments, function secondTaskApiCalls(input, callback) {
         // do a thing for each input
         callback(null, response)
     }, function allDone(err, result) {
         // do a thing with all the results
         // this is called once all results are in OR if err is ever passed 
         // as a truthy value
         callback(null, processedResults)
     })
   } 
},
function handler(err, results) {
    var firstCallResults = results.firstCall;
    // want to also grab five results from five parallel network calls in secondTask
});
```